# Mysql how to search the result of a select statement

Tags: mysql

I have the following query.

```
SELECT
horse_name AS Horse_Name,
GROUP_CONCAT(
    placing_numerical
ORDER BY
    race_date
DESC SEPARATOR
    ', '
) Place
FROM
results
GROUP BY
Horse_Name
```

I would then like to search the results of Place with a LIKE '%xyz%' query. Is there a way to do this in the same query?
Thanks for lokking.

Comment: Yes, but it's a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the info but why is it a bad idea?

Comment: Because relational databases like atomized, not serialized, data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is with a subquery

```
    select *
    from (
      SELECT horse_name AS Horse_Name,  
      GROUP_CONCAT( placing_numerical ORDER BY race_date DESC SEPARATOR ', ' ) Place
) tbl
    Where tbl.Place like '%xyz%'
```

Comment: Hi Jacob, I get this

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'horse_name' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
SELECT
    horse_name AS Horse_Name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        placing_numerical
    ORDER BY
        race_date
    DESC SEPARATOR
        ', '
    ) Place
FROM
    results
GROUP BY
    Horse_Name
```

) tbl
WHERE
    tbl.Place LIKE '%xyz%'

Thanks to Jacob, this works a treat and I now understand more about subqueries.